# Blockfrost.io get transaction data with addresses (from/to)

Tags: cryptocurrency, cryptoapi, cardano

I am looking at using Blockfrost.io API in order to read cardano transactions, I am looking to get the bare minimum which is:

- Address from
- Address to
- Assets transfered (type + amount)
- Fees

So far I can not find how to retrieve a transaction addresses from and to while using:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1txs~1%7Bhash%7D/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D/get)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my question:
Cardano does use something called "utxos" for the way it handles transactions and I would invite everyone to read about these.

Regarding Blockfrost.io, this means you need to have a look at the transactions api:
https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D/get

and also combine it with the utxos api:
[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1txs~1{hash}~1utxos/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D%7E1utxos/get)